# Room SQLite select statement with strftime does not return any result

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have an android app with a database based on the room library.

```
public class Entry {

    public Entry(int cat_id, Date date, float value, String comment) {
        this.date = date;
        this.value = value;
        this.cat_id = cat_id;
        this.comment = comment;
    }
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int entry_id;

    public final Date date;

    public final float value;

    public final int cat_id;

    public final String comment;
}
```

In the EntryDao, I have two select statements that are not working:

```
@Query(("SELECT sum(value) FROM Entry WHERE cat_id = :catId AND strftime('%Y', date) LIKE :year"))
float getSumByCatIdAndYear(int catId, int year);

@Query(("SELECT sum(value) FROM Entry WHERE cat_id = :catId AND strftime('%Y', date) LIKE :year AND strftime('%m', date) LIKE :month"))
float getSumByCatIdAndYearAndMonth(int catId, int year, int month);
```

I don't know why, but it always returns 0.0
I think I have done something wrong with the strftime function, but I am not sure.

Comment: What values are you storing in the `date` column? Has to be a format the [date and time](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) functions understand.

Comment: `val entry = Entry(int(catId), java.sql.Date(date), Float(value), String(comment));` Thats what I store in the table

Comment: What does all that evaluate to? What do the actual values in the column look like?

Comment: What exctly do you mean?

Comment: strftime('%m' will always return 2 digit value, like for January it'll give `01` instead of `1`. So your query is gonna fail cuz you're essentially doing `01` LIKE `1` which returns false. So you need to cast the result to int. something like: 
`CAST(strftime('%m', datetime(date/1000, 'unixepoch')) AS int) = :month`
And that will give you correct result.